# Wix React Native Navigator UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: File not found when build with IOS when I edit AppDelegate.m

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, velo

Hi Guys I am just going to install Wix-react-native-navigator v2 on my RN project, when I edit the AppDelegate.m, error : **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: File not found when build with IOS** appears on my bundler, could anyone can share experience with me?

[Image - AppDelegate.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdXgn.png)

[Image - Metro Bundler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV7KI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just change "index.ios" for "index" in the line below:

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

it's because you have no index.ios.js in your app start script, maybe you only have index.js.